# perl module Class::HPLOO v0.23 install issue #2

Tags: perl, module, installation

Having the exact issue as described at:  [perl module Class::HPLOO v0.23 install issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008870/perl-module-classhploo-v0-23-install-issue), I have attempted to correct the `defined(@array)` problem by editing to just `(@array)` and trying to rebuild the module. However I continue to get the return of:

```
$ make clean
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make
$ make test: *** No rule to
make target `clean:'.  Stop. Manifying 2 pod documents
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/opt/local/bin/perl5.26" "-Iblib/lib" "-Iblib/arch"
test.pl
1..42
# Running under perl version 5.026002 for darwin
# Current time local: Sun Aug 26 06:48:26 2018
# Current time GMT:   Sat Aug 25 22:48:26 2018
# Using Test.pm version 1.26 not ok 1
# Failed test 1 in test.pl at line 9
#  test.pl line 9 is:   ok(!$@) ; Can't locate object method "new" via package "Foo" at test.pl line 11. make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
```

Comment: Change `eval { require "test/classtest.pm" } ` to just `require "test/classtest.pm" ` and see if the `eval ...` is hiding any more errors.

Comment: this returns with: "Can't locate test/classtest.pm in @INC  (you may need to install the test::classtest module)...<snip>". there is no such module.

Comment: because I have little idea of what I am doing I changed `require "test/classtest.pm"` to `require "./test/classtest.pm"`  which brought me to:'Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(\S)( { <-- HERE ) (\S)/ at blib/lib/Class/HPLOO.pm line 1077.
Compilation failed in require at ./test/classtest.pm line 2."

Comment: One by one, following the errors, in each location having "eval { require <snip> }" I changed it to "require ./<snip>". Eventually completing all tests without error. I returned through the file returning the "eval { <snip> }". Again it completed all tests without error and I was able to move on to "make install" without visible faults.

Of course this leads me to the question of: what has changed where I needed to add the ./ at these location when once upon a time it was a working module? Although obviously not for me.

Comment: Mob, in my excitement of success I neglected to thank you. So, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three issues with `Class::HPLOO` (which as I noted before, hasn't been updated since 2005) that make it fail with modern perls.

1. [As discovered in the previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008870/perl-module-classhploo-v0-23-install-issue), 
   the obsolete construct `defined (@array)` is used once in `lib/Class/HPLOO.pm' and three times in`lib/Class/HPLOO/Base.pm`. This construction has been prohibited since v5.22
2. The current directory (`.`) is no longer in `@INC` (as of v5.24, I think). So the lines in `test.pl` like

   ```
   require "test/classtest.pm"
   ```

either all need to be rewritten as

```
    require "./test/classtest.pm"
```

or an easier fix is to put

```
    use lib '.';
```

at the top of the script.

3. There is a regular expression in `lib/Class/HPLOO.pm`, line 1077, with an "unescaped left brace"

   ```
     $sub =~ s/(\S)( {) (\S)/$1$2\n$FIRST_SUB_IDENT  $3/gs ;
   ```

`{` is a regex metacharacter, and since v5.22 it has been illegal to use it in a context where it is not indicating a quantity. The fix, as the error message suggests, is to escape it.

```
      $sub =~ s/(\S)( \{) (\S)/$1$2\n$FIRST_SUB_IDENT  $3/gs ;
```

Make these three changes to the code you download from CPAN and the module should build on modern Perls. If you're feeling helpful, you can submit a bug report (linking to this post, if you want) or even a patch with an email to `bug-Class-HPLOO@rt.cpan.org`

Comment: Thanks Mob, I forgot about the unescaped left brace!

Answer (score 1):

come across this issue today, so I fixed it following the answer above. if anyone want to save some time.

I create a repo with the changes. https://github.com/swuecho/Class_HPLOO.git

Comment: Great! May also consider sending a patch to `bug-Class-HPLOO@rt.cpan.org` so the issue can be fixed in the official distribution also?